# Limits on Branding Sets, Audiences, Page variations

Tags: lightning, community, theme-branding

Discussing some solution architecture with a colleague and the question came up about the theoretical boundaries of varying a lightning community using only the out of the box tools.

I've made some use of the tools available, but have never hit a limit.  Typically I've steered the client away when the number of variations starts to look like a potential scalability issue.

I couldn't find any documentation around actual concrete limits on the following items:

- Branding Sets
- Page Variations
- Audiences

Is anybody aware of any actual limits on these?

Answer (score 1):

You can create up to 1500 Audiences, as mentioned in [Considerations for Audience Targeting in Aura Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_audience_use_considerations.htm&type=5).